# How to find the dimensional analysis for gaussian integrals?

Tags: calculus, gaussian-integral, dimensional-analysis

> **Testing several alternatives**
>
> For the Gaussian integral
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-\alpha x^2}}dx,$$
>   use the three easy-cases tests to evaluate the following candidates for its value.
>
> (a) $\sqrt{\pi}/\alpha\quad$ (b) $1+(\sqrt{\pi} - 1)/\alpha\quad$ (c) $1/\alpha^2 + (\sqrt{\pi} - 1)/\alpha$.

I am using the the book called street mathematics to learn more about dimensional analysis. I am trying to understand a problem in the book. The question is to use dimensional analysis to find the solutions for Gaussian integral.

I tried to understand the question and how to best tackle it but I did not succeed.

The three easy cases referred in the question are:

1. when a = ∞
2. when a = 0
3. when a = 1

what I am trying to understand: is all I have to do put the value (a) in the equation and solve for the integral?

Comment: Dimensional analysis will have to give an answer of the form $C\alpha^n$. Is (a) meant to read $\sqrt{\pi/\alpha}$? (A basic DA, or $y=x\sqrt{\alpha}$, shows the result goes as $1/\sqrt{\alpha}$.)

Comment: Am I missing something about the options? Iirc the definite integral of arbitrary Gaussian function is $\sqrt{\pi/\alpha}$, which is not an option(maybe in one the $\sqrt\cdot$ is on everything or the power in the Gaussian function is also on $\alpha$?, In the latter they still miss an absolute value)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I think you don't have tools to compute this integral. But if you replace $\alpha \in\{0,\infty ,1\}$ in the solutions you have, which solution could make sense ? For example, for $\alpha =\infty $ the integrand is null. What could be a possible answer ? Then continue like this and try to deduce the correct solution.